# How do you avoid security message in IE7 when using HTTPS?

Tags: internet-explorer, https, warnings

In IE7 my web site always causes the browser to prompt a "Security Information" dialogue box:

> This page contains both secure and
>   non-secure items.
>
> Do you want to display the non-secure items?

How can I avoid getting this message when traveling between non-secure and secure pages (HTTP to HTTPS)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make sure all your images, script files, CSS files and so on have HTTPS urls if you're on a secure page.

If you view-source and search for "http:" this will soon tell which one (or more) is wrong.

Example:

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> - Correct
<script src="https://ssl.google.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script> - Correct
<script src="http://www.google.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script> - Wrong
```

Comment: Thanks RoBorg you are correct! I located these miscreants in my Flash detection script: 
"codebase", "http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0",
"pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
Luckily, Adobe redirects the HTTPS links to HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

RoBorg has it dead on. However, it can be tricky sometimes to track down the specific page or item causing the problem. Often it is a broken link that redirects to the "404-page not found" page.

A trick I like to use is to hit the page and answer in the affirmative on the prompt then look at the IIS log entries generated for any rows with an 80 in the port column instead of 443.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you haven't included `http://` explicitly anywhere in your code. If you did then that message will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option in IE to toggle this message when moving from HTTP to HTTPS pages.
In IE7, it's on the advanced tab, second checkbox from the bottom.

There is also a 'Display mixed content' option in IE7, security tab, custom level.
Set it to Enabled for the site level you're accessing the site as.

Comment: You cant ask all the website users to do this :)

Comment: Of course not, but as far as i'm aware that's the only way to remove that message when browsing from a non-secure to a secure webpage.
To remove it from one particular webpage, use RoBorg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to solve odd IE7 security warnings:

I found a case where IE7 incorrectly gives the warning. It happens if using jQuery.get() to add HTML content that has an inline style with a relative url. [See test case](https://venko.net/testing/ie7-test.html).

Possible fixes include:

- using an absolute url
- moving the styles to a CSS files (might need to be loaded on page load)
- using jQuery.load() or some other technique might also help

Answer (score 0):

We use this trick in the HTML5 Boilerplate for a clever request of jQuery off the Google CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

instead of adding any http: or https: in the src. which will work fine in every case